# Drupal 7 UUID features

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My goal is export content to code. I've installed uuid_features module, which seems to do it. But there are no "content" or "taxonomy terms" section on feature creation page. What's the problem? What am I doing wrong? Maybe it doesn`t work in drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

The current dev version of `uuid_features` module fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is connected to API changes in uuid modules http://drupal.org/node/1245582